# SQL Convert VARCHAR Substring to DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server

EDIT: I am in the US, and the datetime is MDY

I am using SQL Server for syntax questions. I have a text column that lists a date in it. It looks like this

```
DATE:05/04/2017 AMOUNT:500
```

This column is the same in every record. I want to specifically see the date portion only, so I used a basic `SUBSTRING`:

```
Select
    Field1, SUBSTRING(Field2, 6, 10)
From 
    Table1
```

Sub `SUBSTRING` does show the date, but it's in `VARCHAR` format.

I tried to do a basic convert like

```
Select
    Field1, CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(Field2, 6, 10))
From 
    Table1
```

But I am getting an error

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Does anyone know how I could successfully extract the date from the string in a date format, so I can link it to other tables?

Comment: I bet you have an invalid date or shifted data in one or more rows.  Try doing a group by on the substring and see if you spot anything that does not look like a valid date.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you [set the DATEFORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-dateformat-transact-sql) of your server to the correct format before attempting the convert.   Since your sample data shown is 05/04/2017, we can't tell you if you have MDY, or DMY, but you should be able to figure it out from the rest of your data.

In addition, if you want to find exactly which rows are causing the conversion error, you can use a [TRY_CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql), available in SQL 2012+, and then investigate the rows where the result of the TRY_CONVERT() is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [dateformat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql).

101 if you are using US standard mm/dd/yyyy
or 
103 if you are using british dd/mm/yyyy

```
declare @temp varchar(30)='DATE:05/04/2017 AMOUNT:500'

Select
CONVERT(DATETIME,SUBSTRING(@temp,6,10),101)
```

result:

```
2017-05-04 00:00:00.000
```